# How to reset Atom packages to default

Tags: atom-editor

I installed Atom editor again only to see all my old packages I installed 1 or 2 years ago.

How can I remove all packages and start fresh with default package set?

Simply reinstalling Atom doesn't seem to work.

OS: Windows

Comment: You forgot to mention your operating system

Answer (score 0):

If you're on windows, my atom seems to be stored at "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\atom". Here I have access to a folder named "packages". Try just deleting that, or checking if the folder gets removed after uninstall

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. This folder was removed after uninstall, but after installing Atom again it reappeared and my custom packages are installed again.